# How was the Microsoft PDP-10 8080 emulator developed?

Tags: history, emulation, software-development, 8080, pdp-10

Altair BASIC, the first version of Microsoft BASIC, was developed using an Intel 8008 emulator, modified to emulate an Intel 8080, running on a PDP-10 computer. This emulator was originally designed by Paul Allen so that he and Bill Gates could create the software for Traf-O-Data.

- How was the original 8008 emulator developed?
- What documents were required?
- How did they ensure that it was a faithful emulation?
- How was this then modified for the 8080?
- What made it able to be modified so quickly?
- What documents were required to do so?
- What modifications to the emulator were made to fit specific behaviours of the Altair 8800?

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you are expecting, unless someone digs up this particular emulator source or documentation. From a ten-thousend feet view, software development on a PDP-10 isn't that different from software development on any other computer, so the answer would be "the emulator was developed and modified in the same way as any other emulator on any other system". And cross-development was pretty common back then.

Comment: @dirkt I'm looking for some information about how this was done - both general and specific information would be good (general only as applies to this instance). I've got a tag left, so I'll add [tag:history] to make this clearer.

Comment: Paul Allen's biography "Idea Man" explains the story in a lot of detail.

Comment: @tofro I'll see if I can have a look at that biography.

Comment: If nobody digs up info about this particular emulator, there is a life PDP-8 emulator under TOPS-20 (also PDP-10, though Paul Allen likely used TOPS-10) on the [twenex](http://www.twenex.org/) site, sources included (directory `<PDP-8>`)>

Comment: Designing an emulator for an early 8-bit CPU that only needs to be able to run a program you're developing isn't that hard. It's not like trying to make an emulator for entire an personal computer or video game console that needs to run every game made for it. My guess at the answers would be: Like any other software. The 8008 User's Manual. It wasn't particularly faithful. Like any other software. It's not that hard. The 8080 User's Manual. None.

Comment: @RossRidge If the answer to the latter was None... Why "Out in Albuquerque, Ed Roberts got a call from Gates asking for details about how the Altair handled specific routines. No one had ever asked that before, and Roberts began to get interested." https://web.archive.org/web/20120323162142/http://startup.nmnaturalhistory.org/gallery/story.php?ii=20&sid=4 part 4?

Comment: My guess would be because they needed to make modifications to their BASIC interpreter to fit the specific behaviours of the Altair 8800.

Comment: @RossRidge But how could they test that those modifications would work other than by modifying the emulator to behave in a similar way then running it on the emulator? _Paper?_ :-) I suspect that the answers aren't as simple as that - that's why I asked the question. They might well be, but I'm hoping for something interesting to come out of this.

Comment: My guess is that they used a real Altair 8800 to test it. The emulator would've been a tool to speed up development, but it couldn't replace testing on the actual hardware. From your link that appears to be what happened. They weren't sure it would work until they ran it on an actual Altair 8800. A comment in the source code, "FOR SIMULATOR FIXUPS", suggests that it was conditionally assembled according to whether it would be run on the emulator not, making the code for the emulator and the Altair different. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Altair_Basic_Sign.jpg

Comment: @RossRidge They didn't initially, as far as I know.

Comment: As I said, the article you linked confirms my guess. They were only able to test whether it worked on an a Altair 8800 by taking to it MITS and running it on an Altair 8800. Their testing on the emulator only tested whether it worked on the emulator.

Comment: @RossRidge That "conditional assembly" hypothesis seems quite plausible.If you can find some more like that, it might be enough for an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67693/discussion-on-question-by-wizzwizz4-how-was-the-microsoft-pdp-10-8080-emulator-d).

Comment: @JeremyP See above.

Comment: @RossRidge See above.

Comment: How can we get this question opened again? I've been wanting to know this  forever and would love to see more people contribute to the answers.

Comment: @LateralTerminal I'll create a question asking about the original 8008 simulator, then (if that's narrow enough) create one about the modification to 8080.

Comment: @LateralTerminal [Here you go](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4984/278). Any suggestions to ensure that that one isn't too broad?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think it's a good question. Hopefully It will inspire some good answers too! I'm eagerly awaiting the results :D I especially like "How did they ensure that it was a faithful emulation before their machine was built?"

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing here, but I suspect they started from Intel's own **INTERP/8** 8008 simulator. This was supplied on tape for PDP-10 as FORTRAN IV source. While I can't find the source of INTERP/8, the manual is an appendix of this Lawrence Livermore report "[SIlMULATOR  PROGRAM  FOR  THE  INTEL  MCS-8  800  CPU](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/4429980/)" [PDF]. Intel's simulator for the 8080, INTERP/80, was released in 1973 in a similar format. Original source for INTERP/80 is available [here](http://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack/).

The instructions for the 8008 and 8080 are quite similar, so it wouldn't be a superhuman effort to modify the Intel simulator. As the BIOS of these early micros didn't need to be much more than "print a char / read a char / write to port / read from port", even a very crude simulator would be of immense help.

Comment: According to the Altair BASIC Wikipedia page, "Gates and Allen had neither an interpreter nor even an Altair system on which to develop and test one. However, Allen had written an Intel 8008 emulator for their previous venture Traf-O-Data that ran on a PDP-10 time-sharing computer. He adapted this emulator based on the Altair programmer guide, and they developed and tested the interpreter on Harvard's PDP-10."

Comment: but does it say that Allen wrote it from scratch? Intel wanted their processors used, so they provided tools like simulators to aid developers.

Comment: Wasn't "write to port / read from port" already handled by the CPU?

Comment: the raw instructions are, but where the ports are in the memory map depends on the hardware. That's where CP/M's BIOS ironed out differences: each vendor could have completely different ports for console/printer/disk I/O, but the BIOS allowed one call for all C/PM systems to do the same thing.

Comment: "Allen then started developing a simulator program on the 
university  computer  that  would  emulate  the  Intel  8008  
microprocessor." from [here, p4](http://www.retrocomputing.net/info/allan/eBook06.pdf#4) implies that he wrote it from scratch. Also, "Access to the DEC PDP-10 allowed 
Allen to complete his Intel 8008 simulator program" between "the fall of 1972" and "the fall of 1973". On page 5 it is also referred to as "Allen's simulation program", but other programs are referred to as not his: "He also adapted assembler 
and debugger programs for the Intel 8080."

Comment: On page 6, "Allen's  simulator  and  Gates  
interpreter  had  functioned  without  a  problem.  This  was  
an incredible achievement." If Allen had based his simulator on Intel's (already working) simulator, this wouldn't have been anywhere near as much of an achievement. Also, a document of this much detail would _almost surely_ mention if the simulator was based on another program.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 there are a lot of words in Roy A. Allen's “A History Of The 
Personal Computer”, but it is a self-published work. Looks like the early pre-Microsoft information there comes from interviews in TIME and Fortune magazines. Both of these are non-technical magazines, and Gates and Allen have never been shy of personal promotion. Roy Allen's book even suggests (ch.6, p.3) that Gates's first interpreter was based on one of the free BASICs distributed by DECUS for the PDP/8 …

Comment: If there's relevant information from that book, consider quoting it in your answer. IANAL, but afaik that counts as fair use.